# Converting a variable from a type stored in other variable C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, type-conversion

I need to convert a dynamic variable from a type stored in other variable.

For example:

```
dynamic dynamicVar = 3;
string type = "double";
var valueConverted = (type) dynamicVar;
```

I know this is not working but, is there a way to do something like that?

I'm receving a JSON like that:

```
 

       [
            {
                "name": "Parameter1",
                "description": "Description",
                "value": "Value",
                "type": "string"
            },
                {
                "name": "Parameter1",
                "description": "Description",
                "value": false,
                "type": "boolean"
        
            },
                {
                "name": "Parameter3",
                "description": "Description",
                "value": 3,
                "type": "double"
            }
        ]
```

I need to convert this json into a object like that:

```
public class Parameters
    {
        public string Parameter1 { get; set; }

        public bool Parameter2 { get; set; }

        public double? Parameter3 { get; set; }
}
```

When I tried to store the Parameter3, I've received the error:
*cannot convert Int to Double*

Comment: C# is statically typed. I dont think something like this is possible in c#. But you could do a switch case statement that achives that.

Comment: What is actual use for something like this? Looks like [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, TBH. Can you please provide more info about actual usage/code?

Comment: I'm creating a list of parameters to show in frontend, and when I received this list back I have to store the values typed.
I will use this code in a Mapper Class, converting from a Json to a Object.

Comment: Why dont you just use an existing json serializer that maps json into model classes?

Comment: @FrederikPietzko Yes, actually I did the switch case, but I was looking for a better approach.

Comment: Because, the Json I'm receiving there is no same structure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you can do is first generate JSON schema from [your JSON](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/wiki/SampleJsonSchemaGenerator):

```cs
    var schema = JsonSchema.FromSampleJson("...");
```

Then you can use [NJsonSchema](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema) to generate the class from it. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) magic to set those field. Something like this (I use Newtonsoft Json.NET as json library) :

```
    class Parameters
    {
        public string Parameter1 { get; set; }
        public bool Parameter2 { get; set; }
        public double Parameter3 { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{nameof(Parameter1)}: {Parameter1}, {nameof(Parameter2)}: {Parameter2}, {nameof(Parameter3)}: {Parameter3}";
        }
    }

        var json = @"     [
            {
                ""name"": ""Parameter1"",
                ""description"": ""Description"",
                ""value"": ""Value"",
                ""type"": ""string""
            },
            {
                ""name"": ""Parameter2"",
                ""description"": ""Description"",
                ""value"": false,
                ""type"": ""boolean""
            },
            {
                ""name"": ""Parameter3"",
                ""description"": ""Description"",
                ""value"": 3,
                ""type"": ""double""
            }
        ]";

        var typeMap = new Dictionary<string, Type>
        {
            {"double", typeof(double)},
            {"boolean", typeof(bool)},
            {"string", typeof(string)},
        };

        var jArray = JArray.Parse(json);

        var result = new Parameters();

        var methodInfo = typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions).GetMethod("Value", 1, new []{typeof(IEnumerable<JToken>)});

        foreach (var jObj in jArray)
        {
            var method = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeMap[jObj["type"].Value<string>()]);
            var value = method.Invoke(null, new[] {jObj["value"]});
            typeof(Parameters).GetProperty(jObj["name"].Value<string>())
                .SetValue(result, value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result); //  prints "Parameter1: Value, Parameter2: False, Parameter3: 3"
```

This code can be improved vastly with different kinds of exception handling, caching and so on but should give you a general idea about how you can approach your task (if I understood it correctly).

Also if you will stick with Json.NET lib you can think about encapsulating this in a [custom converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dynamic dynamicVar = 3;
var valueConverted = default(dynamicVar.GetType()); //This will set the right type
valueConverted = dynamicVar;
```